# How to configure view for all categories in a step?

Tags: category, system-configuration

In **categories --> single category --> view settings** you can choose:

- *available product listing sort by*
- *default product listing sort by*

I need to change these 2 values for all categories in a single step avoiding to make it for every single categories by hand.

How to change these **configuration settings**?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It's possibile to config the default Sort Order for Store / Website / following [this guide](http://inchoo.net/magento/changing-default-category-sort-order-in-magento/)